# time_format configuration in fluent.conf

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, fluentd

What is the correct *time_format* for following date and time format in fluent.conf configuration.

```
12/Apr/2021:12:17:03.747 +0530
```

I tried with below but not sure whether it is correct because access logs are not printing in the Kibana.

```
time_format %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%3N %z
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work with following format.

```
time_format %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S.%N %z
```

Thanks.